# react-native pass data to parent navigation from second navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Here is a part of the code of second screen:

```
    state = {
      hasCameraPermission: null,
      barcodeValue : ""
    }

    FunctionToOpenFirstActivity = () =>
    {
        this.props.navigation.navigate('First', { barcodeValue: this.state.barcodeValue });
    }

    //after barcode was scanned
    handleBarCodeScanned = ({ type, data }) => {
        this.state.barcodeValue = data;
        alert(this.state.barcodeValue);

        this.FunctionToOpenFirstActivity();

    }
```

Here is a part of the code of parent screen in render ()

```
   <View style={styles.firstrow}>
       <View style={styles.inputWrap}>
         <Text style={styles.label}>Barcode Value</Text>
         <TextInput style={styles.input}>{this.props.barcodeValue}</TextInput>
       </View>
   </View>
```

this.props.barcodeValue is blank, anyone knows what is the problem?

Comment: try changing `this.props.barcodeValue` to `this.props.navigation.getParam('barcodeValue')`

Comment: @janotama , thanks, it works. I read through almost all related thread of stackoverflow but can't even saw something like "getParam". You can add an answer

Comment: okay, i'm glad that works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as you can find inside the documentation https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/params.html, you can read the params that passed from previous view using `this.props.navigation.getParam(paramName, defaultValue)`, `defaultValue` is optional

in your case, try changing `this.props.barcodeValue` to `this.props.navigation.getParam('barcodeValue')`